# Ограничение посещения страницы в определенное время дня, ночи

Tags: php

Например, на страницу можно заходить от часа ночи до 2 часов ночи, а в остальное время, чтобы выбивало: "Сейчас не время для посещения данной странице". Спасибо заранее.

Comment: @oOKomarOo, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к предложениям выполнить работу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**php**

```
if(date('H')=='01'){
//показываем
}else{
//прятаем
}
```

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} !^01$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /close.html [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так попробовать:

```
if(date('H:i') >= '01:00' && date('H:i') < '02:00'){
   echo "Заходи, дорогой!";
} else {
   echo "У нас закрыто!";
}
```

Comment: на целую минуту больше положенного сайт будет в доступе..

Comment: Вы наш проницательный ))) 

    date('H:i') < '02:00'